# grails images absolute path

Tags: image, grails

I have this image in my header template `<img src="images/slide-1.jpg" alt="Slide #1" width="175" height="77" />`

When the template is used from a gsp file inside the 'main' directory, the image is loaded. Although, if I have the same template being used inside a gsp file inside a controller, the image is not loaded. I have tried to change this:

```
<img src="images/slide-1.jpg" alt="Slide #1" width="175" height="77" />
```

to this:

```
<img src="../images/slide-1.jpg" alt="Slide #1" width="175" height="77" />
```

and it works, but now the image in the other page don't. Any idea to solve the problem? I know the key must be absolute path. But i've done some searches and found nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put your images in resource folder (for example, in `YOUR_PROJECT/web-app/images`) then access it in gsp by [resource tag](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/resource.html). By this way you won't have the absolute path problem.

For a concrete example, you can refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243467/displaying-image-in-gsp-grails-get-link-from-database).

Answer (score 2):

Try "${application.contextPath}/images/slide-1.jpg". It's a semi-absolute path that will work in any of your deployment environments.