# Grails - show File image in <g:img> tag?

Tags: java, html, file, grails, bytea

I'm having an issue when showing an image on  or  tags.

I have an image that is stored in pg database, (BYTEA) but I just can't get it working...

I have already tried`<img src = "$ {object.file}" /> ',' <g: img file = "$ {object.file}" /`> and some other variations, but it did not work ..
Note: if i just put '$ {} `object.file into my html, the file name is shown.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display image in grails GSP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259320/how-to-display-image-in-grails-gsp)

Comment: does this topic shows how to retrieve a img file from database and show it in the html?